# woocommerce add_to_cart function not add two different products in cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i am creating a custom button to add products to cart using add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity) function. It's working well for the single property but when I change product_id with another product id then it shows error.

$cart = $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity);

when I try same with different product_ids it stops working.
any solution?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @AkshayShah it return false when I change product id

Comment: What is the value of new $product_id that you change to? Does it really exist?

Comment: @NerijusMasikonis first time i used it with $product_id = 85 i work properly. Now when i change $product_id = 93 it return false. but for $product_id = 85 still working well and increase its quantity in cart. and yes both product_ids exist .

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks for the help. Finally, the problem is solved. Actually, 93 product_id product is out of stock that's why it returns false. add_to_cart() function does not work with a product out of stock.

Comment: If you enable stock management at product level (option in inventory tab) and you "allow backorders" (option), `add_to_cart()` function will work…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Yeah I checked all the options. Now it working well.